# Sum of squares and regular polygons

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Someone has proposed to me a problem that I am trying to solve and I invite others to solve it.

Find the locus described by the points such that the sum of the squares of their distances to each of the vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides is equal to a fixed square $m^2$.

NB- *The integer $m$ obviously must be greater than a certain constant and the solution involves some trigonometric identities that might appear as difficult*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the polygon be
$p_k
=(x_k, y_k)
=(\cos(2k\pi/n), \sin(2k\pi/n))
=(\cos(kt), \sin(kt))
$,
for $k=0$ to $n-1$,
$t = 2\pi/n$.

The distance from
a point $p = (x, y)$
to $p_k$ is

$\begin{array}\\
d_k
&=\sqrt{|p-p_k|}\\
&=\sqrt{(x-\cos(kt))^2+(y-\sin(kt))^2}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2-2x\cos(kt)+\cos^2(kt)+y^2-2y\sin(kt)+\sin^2(kt)}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2(x\cos(kt)-y\sin(kt))}\\
\end{array}
$

If
$p = r(\cos(u), \sin(u))
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
d_k
&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2(x\cos(kt)+y\sin(kt))}\\
&=\sqrt{r^2-2(r\cos(u)\cos(kt)+r\sin(u)\sin(kt))}\\
&=\sqrt{r^2-2r\cos(u-kt)}\\
\text{so}\\
d_k^2
&=r^2-2r\cos(u-kt)\\
\end{array}
$

Summing

$\begin{array}\\
D
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(r^2-2r\cos(u-kt))\\
&=nr^2-2r\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(u-kt)\\
&=nr^2-2r\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}Re(e^{i(u-kt)})\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i(u-kt)}\\
&=nr^2-2rRe(e^{iu}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-ikt})\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}\dfrac{1-e^{-int}}{1-e^{-it}}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}\dfrac{1-\cos(-nt)-i\sin(-nt)}{1-\cos(-t)-i\sin(-t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}\dfrac{1-\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)}{1-\cos(t)+i\sin(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}\dfrac{1-\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)}{1-\cos(t)+i\sin(t)}\dfrac{1-\cos(t)-i\sin(t)}{1-\cos(t)-i\sin(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}
\dfrac{(1-\cos(nt))(1-\cos(t))+\sin(nt)\sin(t)+i(\sin(nt)(1-\cos(t))-\sin(t)(1-\cos(nt)}{(1-\cos(t))^2+\sin^2(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}
\dfrac{1-\cos(nt)-\cos(t)+\cos(nt)\cos(t)+\sin(nt)\sin(t)+i(\sin(nt)-\sin(nt)\cos(t))-\sin(t)+\sin(t)\cos(nt)}{2-2\cos(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(e^{iu}
\dfrac{a(t)+ib(t)}{2-2\cos(t)}\right)
\qquad\text{(getting lazy here)}\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(
\dfrac{(\cos(u)+i\sin(u))(a(t)+ib(t))}{2-2\cos(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-2rRe\left(
\dfrac{(\cos(u)a(t)-\sin(u)b(t))+i(\cos(u)b(t)+\sin(u)a(t))}{2-2\cos(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-r\left(
\dfrac{\cos(u)a(t)-\sin(u)b(t)}{1-\cos(t)}\right)\\
&=nr^2-r\left(
\dfrac{\cos(u)v\cos(c)-\sin(u)v\sin(c)}{1-\cos(t)}\right)
\qquad\text{if } (a(t), b(t))=v(\cos(c), \sin(c))\\
&=nr^2-rv\left(
\dfrac{\cos(u+c)}{2\sin^2(t/2)}\right)
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
we want
$m^2
=nr^2-rv\left(
\dfrac{\cos(u+c)}{2\sin^2(t/2)}\right)
$.

So,
find $v$ and $u$
which satisfies this.

Your turn.

Comment: The locus is a circumference that, depending on the magnitude of $m^2$, may not exist, or be inside or outside the polygon.

Comment: Whitout exponentials we can do
$$m^2=nr^2+n\overline{OP}^2-2r\overline{OP}(\cos(x)+\cos(x+a)+\cos(x+2a)+\cdots $$ and the last parenthesis is equal to $0$ whatever be $x$ because of telescopic
$$\cos(a+b)\cos(a-b)=\cos^2(a)-\cos^2(b)\\\cos(b+c)\cos(b-c)=\cos^2(b)-\cos^2(b)\\............\\$$